# Clamp output voltage from DAC

Tags: voltage, clamp

Hi all my analog friends!  I have what is probably a very simple problem and I am just overthinking it--but when I work in the analog world, I always feel like I'm missing something.  My problem is this:  I have a 20-bit DAC which can output +/-10V, but I need to clamp it to +/-5V (or up to about +/- 5.5V).  Basically I have a 2X gain output amp, then TVS ESD protection, then my output.  The voltages I have available to me are +/- 15V, +5V, +12V.  Obviously, if I had +/- 5V, I would clamp it with Schottky diodes--what is my next simplest option?  This is purely to protect external devices from the board not being set up correctly, not for normal operation.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why not use a potential divider on the output.

Answer (score 1):

If your output amplifier can be clamped at a reasonable current **and** it can supply an extra 1mA or so you can use a couple [TL431](https://www.ti.com/document-viewer/TL431/datasheet) chips with a couple resistors each to set the clamp voltage. Two equal resistors (eg. 10K/10K) will set the voltage to close to 5V, plus you will need two Schottky diodes for bipolar output.

The part will clamp 100mA however you should calculate the thermal effects to make sure the part will not overheat if whatever maximum short-circuit current your amplifier can supply is maintained continuously.

The below circuit will clamp at a nominal voltage of about +/-5.3V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFSRGQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's generally risky to try clamping with diodes to a supply rail because the rail is not necessarily capable of sinking current. For example, if you use an LM7805 regulator to create a +5V rail and connected a diode to the op-amp output, the regulator output would simply increase with the op-amp output minus a diode drop and no clamping would take place at all (just a bit of current into the divider network in the regulator).

Comment: Your circuit needs fixing Spehro. However, it's a sound idea but might need series resistors for limiting current into the 431s. Also, they could be used in series if you look at the DS (up to -100 mA current).

Comment: @Andyaka If it's a standard op-amp with 25mA~30mA current limit it should work as-is. Series resistors would affect the accuracy/distortion. Putting the limiters in series would eliminate the diodes but would have to use unequal value resistors to get OP's desired voltage limit.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany That's a great idea--but I think it may require too much current in my case.  I have a supply capable of 150mA, supplying 3 amplifiers with a short-circuit current of +55mA/-62mA--the OPA1611.  All 3 amplifier outputs could potentially need clamping at the same time.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I have another question if you wouldn't mind guiding me a little bit more--I need to be able to switch this clamp in and out of the circuit, but any part with any resistance will render the clamp ineffective.  I can't use a regular relay because I need several (6) of these clamps and space is limited (FMC form factor)--do you have any ideas on how to accomplish this?